# CLR SQL Assembly: Get the Bytestream?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, clr, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR dll I want to deploy, but have found you can embed the byte stream/varbinary_literal/ varbinary_expression/assembly bits into a text file to get around the messy hassle of packaging a DLL and making sure it's accessible for the [CREATE ASSEMBLY command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx).

But what I have yet to find is how to get that byte stream/varbinary_literal/ varbinary_expression/assembly bits value.  I haven't found any consistent terminology, and what I keep finding in using `Load()`.

Comment: SELECT @assemblyBinary = AF.content
FROM sys.assemblies AS A
INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files AS AF
ON A.assembly_id = AF.assembly_id
WHERE A.name = 'Assembly_CLRFunction'

Comment: I'd say the correct terminology would be a hex string

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's just a hex representation of the dll. This bit should do the trick:

```
    static string GetHexString(string assemblyPath)
    {
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(assemblyPath))
            assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, assemblyPath);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("0x");

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(assemblyPath,
              FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            int currentByte = stream.ReadByte();
            while (currentByte > -1)
            {
                builder.Append(currentByte.ToString("X2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                currentByte = stream.ReadByte();
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

You should use the resulting string like so:

```
string hexString = GetHexString(assemblyPath);
string sql = "CREATE ASSEMBLY [" + assemblyName + "] FROM " + hexString + 
             " WITH PERMISSION_SET = " + somePermissionSet;
```

Comment: Thanks - the hex info led me to this code: http://blog.waldenl.com/2009/12/command-line-hex-representation-of-file.html

Comment: that's basically the same loop yes :)

Answer (score 9):

Found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/d0bb9a61-6703-46f5-8e23-4d3818bf9cb7/how-to-obtain-assemblybits-in-create-assembly-command-sql-server-2008?forum=sqlnetfx#00da9d0a-5d63-4598-b40c-8f9586d54c48), the `varbinary` can be generated  without custom code for generating it, only by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and a local SQL Server instance.

1. `create` or `alter` your assembly in your database using its local path on your local SQL Server.

   ```sql
   use yourBase
   go
   create assembly YourAssemblySqlName from N'YourLocalPath\YourAssemblyFile.dll'
   go
   ```
2. Browse to your assembly in Object Explorer.

   [image: Browsing to assembly]
3. Script its creation.

   [image: Scripting the assembly]

And SSMS gives you the `varbinary`.

Comment: You can also get it like this:
`SELECT af.content FROM sys.assemblies a
INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files af ON a.assembly_id = af.assembly_id 
WHERE 
 a.name = <@assemblyName>`

Comment: @rahvin_t Nice query, but in the 'where' clause, you probably want to target/change to the 'af' alias rather than "a" alias - as in 'af.name = ...', in case of a (debug) 'PDB' assembly has been loaded too.