# Create a User defined function like SQL server 2017 STRING_AGG on earlier versions

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, string-aggregation

I try to create a generic function that can be used like [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql#f-generate-a-sorted-list-of-emails-per-towns) of using the new string_agg built-in function on SQL Server 2017

the inside implementation can be something like the follow

```
with tbl as(
   select a.Id, c.Desc
     from TableA a
     join TableB b on b.aId = a.Id
     join TableC c on c.Code = b.bCode 
)  
select distinct ID
     , STUFF(( select ', ' + Desc from tbl t where t.ID = tbl.ID 
            for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') Desc   
from tbl
```

But how to receives  the field key, the field to be connected, the separator char, and the scoped select context? 
Is it related to [`Inline` or `Multi-Statement Table-Valued Functions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554333/multi-statement-table-valued-function-vs-inline-table-valued-function) ?

Comment: Aggregate functions can be imported via DLLs. You have to write class in C# or other .NET language and then import it to SSMS. But you don't need such function, there's nice example how to aggregate strings using `for xml` clause.

Comment: Can't be done in T-SQL. You'd need dynamic SQL, and functions can't use that. There's a reason `STRING_AGG` was added to the language. A custom CLR aggregate can do it, but there's no need for you to reinvent the wheel in that case; plenty of examples of that on the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, well *can't be done* is not quite true :-D (although I'd not recommend my "*solution*" :-D )

Comment: @Shnugo: Meh. I stand by the letter of my comment, in that you can't do it without rewriting the original query -- specifically, your approach requires duplicating the `GROUP BY` and introducing a subquery, neither of which `STRING_AGG` requires. As far as the spirit goes, though, I'll readily acknowledge your answer comes as close as you can get.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's more kind of a joke :-D

Comment: Hi @MichałTurczyn thanks for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregate-invoking-functions#example-1) nice direction =) and no, it's not duplicates - i was showing how to do it - just looking for a function for essayer  using on the future .

Comment: @Shnugo: there are no jokes on Stack Overflow. Only bad hacks and people innocent enough to copy and paste them. :-P (I've written a few myself, no judgement here...)

Comment: @JeroenMostert The idea to pass a sub-select as implicitly casted XML can be very usefull though. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204) I provide a generic function creating an `HTML` table out of any `SELECT` you pass into. For the given case it was better to use the `STUFF-FOR XML`-hack directly within the statement, rather than call an UDF...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.. so with the first comment of @MichałTurczyn I run into [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregate-invoking-functions#example-1) Microsoft article about *CLR User-Defined Aggregate - Invoking Functions*

Once I compile the code into SrAggFunc.dll, I was trying to register the aggregate in SQL Server as follows:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [STR_AGG] FROM 'C:\tmp\STR_AGG.dll'; 
GO
```

But I got the following error.

> Msg 6501, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not open the physical file 'C:\tmp\SrAggFunc.dll': 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

So I used [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886013/1509853) excellant part of @SanderRijken code and then change the command to

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [STR_AGG] 
FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FF......000; --from GetHexString function
GO
```

and then,

```
CREATE AGGREGATE [STR_AGG] (@input nvarchar(200)) RETURNS nvarchar(max) 
EXTERNAL NAME [STR_AGG].C_STRING_AGG;`
```

Now it's done.

You can see it under your Database -> Programmability on SSMS

[image: Aggregate Functions && Assemblies]

and used like :

```
SELECT a.Id, [dbo].[STR_AGG](c.Desc) cDesc
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b on b.aId = a.Id
JOIN TableC c on c.Code = b.bCode 
GROUP BY a.Id
```

Thanks all =)

Comment: Great that you've found a good solution! Your problem with the path might come from the fact, that SqlServer is not seeing the same `c:` as you in many installations

Comment: One question: what about the sort order? You might add a parameter for this, otherwise this can be random

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is an ugly hack, I have to go and wash my hands now, but it works (in a way :-D)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyStringAgg(@SelectForXmlAuto XML,@Delimiter NVARCHAR(10))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN STUFF((
             SELECT @Delimiter + A.nd.value(N'(@*)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
             FROM @SelectForXmlAuto.nodes(N'/*') AS A(nd)
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
           ).value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),1,LEN(@Delimiter),'');
END
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(GroupId INT,SomeValue NVARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'A1'),(1,'A2'),(2,'B1'),(3,'C1'),(3,'C2'),(3,'C3');

SELECT GroupId
      ,dbo.MyStringAgg((SELECT SomeValue 
                        FROM @tbl AS t2 
                        WHERE t2.GroupId=t.GroupId 
                        FOR XML AUTO), N', ')
FROM @tbl AS t
GROUP BY GroupId;
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyStringAgg;
```

The result

```
1    A1, A2
2    B1
3    C1, C2, C3
```

The *parameter* is a `FOR XML` sub-select within paranthesis. This will implicitly pass the sub-selects result as an XML into the function.

### To be honest: I would not use this myself...

A query like this

```
SELECT GroupId
      ,STUFF((SELECT N', ' + SomeValue 
              FROM @tbl AS t2 
              WHERE t2.GroupId=t.GroupId 
              FOR XML PATH,TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
FROM @tbl AS t
GROUP BY GroupId;
```

produces the same result and is almost the same amount of typing - but should be faster then calling a slow UDF...