# How to convert STRING_AGG to stuff function to work query on SQL Server 2016 below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have below SQL query which is not working on SQL Server 2016 and below version

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(d.Name, ',') AS divnames 
        FROM (
            SELECT div.name, MHLId 
            FROM MsrtProfile mp 
            INNER JOIN Division div ON mp.DivisionId = div.Id 
            WHERE mp.mhlid = ph.potentialHospitalNo  
            GROUP BY div.Name, MHLId
        ) d
    ) AS divisionnames
FROM xyz ph
```

Example my output will come like below

```
div1,div2,div3
```

I need with comma values of single column rows.

I have two tables are following below - first table name is `Hospital`:

```
hospitalId   name
-----------------
1            a1
2            a2
```

Second table name is `division`

```
id  DivisionName    hospitalId
------------------------------
1     d1             1
2     d2             1
3     d3             2
```

I need an output like below by join first and second table by hospitalid

```
DivisionName
-------------
d1,d2
d3
```

Comment: i have updated more clarification questions. @DaleK

Comment: you can make a string_agg dll and then make custom function for this. 
Follow this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804363/6467840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a pretty straight-forward query with `STRING_AGG` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    h.HospitalId, h.Name,
    STRING_AGG(d.DivisionName, ',') AS DivisonName
FROM 
    dbo.Division d
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Hospital h ON h.HospitalId = d.HospitalId
GROUP BY
    h.HospitalId, h.Name
```

**UPDATE**

For versions **before** SQL Server **2017**, you need to use the `FOR XML PATH` approach - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    h.HospitalId, h.Name,
    STUFF ((SELECT ',' + d.DivisionName
            FROM @Division d
            WHERE d.HospitalId = h.HospitalId
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM 
    @Hospital h 
GROUP BY
    h.HospitalId, h.Name
```

Comment: i dont want using STRING_AGG is not working in latest sql version. @marc_s

Comment: STRING_AGG is working on older sql server versions and not working on new version sql servers. @marc_s

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan: `STRING_AGG` was introduced in SQL Server **2017**; and it works just fine in 2017, 2019 and 2022 versions of SQL Server. Why not use it, when it's available?? ,,

Comment: my question query is working in older version but prodcution this query is not working   SELECT
    (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(d.Name, ',') AS divnames 
        FROM (
            SELECT div.name, MHLId 
            FROM MsrtProfile mp 
            INNER JOIN Division div ON mp.DivisionId = div.Id 
            WHERE mp.mhlid = ph.potentialHospitalNo  
            GROUP BY div.Name, MHLId
        ) d
    ) AS divisionnames
FROM xyz ph . @marc_s

Comment: and what is this link is saying: stackoverflow.com/a/48804363/6467840  .@marc_s

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan: what version is your production server then?? `STRING_AGG` works in SQL Server **2017 and newer**  but ***NOT*** in older versions than 2017 ....

Comment: sorry i have 2016 server version in production. @marc_s

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan: updated with an approach that'll work in older SQL Server versions, without `STRING_AGG`

Comment: thanks i will check and update your answer.